# Difference between node.next = node and node=node.next

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm now a little confusing between these 2 code:

```
node = node.next;
node.next = node;

public class ListNode
    {
      public int val;
      public ListNode next;
      public ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
    }
```

It seems like both of them works fine somehow, but functions in different ways. I'm not confusing between them, could some explain the difference for me?

Thanks

Comment: What part are you confused by? What do you think is the difference? Try something like `var node = new ListNode (1); node.next = new ListNode(2);`. Then try out the two lines you're confused by and see what the difference is. If you're still confused, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Pronounce `=` as 'becomes'. It'a `a=b` vs `b=a` .

Comment: @RufusL To my understand,  node = node.next means I'm changing my pointer to next node, node.next = node means I'm linking my node to a node.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide much context, but let's say we have following LinkedList: a->b->c->d->e (characters represent ListNodes and arrow is `next` property).

And then we have `ListNode node` variable currently pointing to node `c` inside list.

(1) First assignment `node = node.next` does not change anything in original list but changes value of `node`. After assignment LinkedList stays at: a->b->c->d->e and `node` points to `d`

(2) Another assignment `node.next = node` changes list. Rest of list (d,e) are discarded and c starts pointing to itself forever: a->b->c->c->c->c->c.. `node` stays pointing to `c`

Comment: You should mention that in (1) after executing `node = node.next` that if `node` originally points to `c` that `node` will now point to `d`.

Comment: Similarly, for (2) mention that `node` still points to `c`. You've established that it certainly forms a tight loop in the list where c->c, but didn't mention about what happens (or does not happen) to the `node` variable.  (You just made the change.  thx)